Unable to deploy Node.js app on A2Hosting - ENOENT: no such file or directory
Unable to deploy my node app on A2Hosting, getting below error:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/eduonli1/portfolio_app/public/index.html'

Node deployment page:
Run NPM Install is successful, but Run JS script keeps loading

Anyways, when I go the url, I get:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/eduonli1/portfolio_app/public/index.html'
But the file exist in the above path:

My overall folder structure:
portfolio/
│
├── app.js
├── package.json
├── public/
│   ├── css/
│   │   ├── styles.css
│   ├── js/
│   │   ├── script.js
│   ├── images/
│   │   ├── image1.jpg
│   │   └── image2.png
│   ├── fonts/
│   │   ├── font1.woff
│   │   └── font2.ttf
│   └── html/
│       ├── index.html
│       └── mail-success.html
└── .htaccess

app.js:
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const path = require("path");
const rateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");

dotenv.config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3131;

// Middleware to parse JSON bodies
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Serve static files
app.use("/assets", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public", "assets")));
app.use("/css", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public", "css")));
app.use("/js", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public", "js")));

// Rate limiting middleware
const limiter = rateLimit({
    windowMs: 60 * 60 * 1000, // 1 hour
    max: 5, // limit each IP to 5 requests per windowMs
    message: "Too many requests from this IP, please try again later",
});

app.use("/send-email", limiter);

// Route to handle form submission
app.post("/send-email", (req, res) => {
    const { name, email, message } = req.body;

    console.log("Form data received:", { name, email, message });

    // Create a Nodemailer transporter
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: "Gmail",
        auth: {
            user: process.env.GMAIL_USER,
            pass: process.env.GMAIL_PASS,
        },
    });

    // Email message options
    const mailOptions = {
        from: email,
        to: process.env.RECIPIENT_EMAIL,
        subject: "New contact form submission",
        text: `Name: ${name}\nEmail: ${email}\nMessage: ${message}`,
    };

    console.log("Attempting to send email with options:", mailOptions);

    // Send email
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error("Error sending email:", error);
            res.status(500).send("Failed to send email");
        } else {
            console.log("Email sent successfully:", info.response);
            // Send mail-success.html
            res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public", "mail-success.html"), () => {
                // Redirect to index.html after 5 seconds
                setTimeout(() => {
                    res.redirect("/");
                }, 5000);
            });
        }
    });
});

// Serve index.html for root path
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public", "index.html"));
});


// Start server
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});



Since the index.html file is inside html folder, you have set the serving folder wrong
instead of res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public", "index.html")); , try res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public", "html", "index.html"));

There were few issues with my deployment:

Path for HTML
Passing a port through CPanel
Editing .htaccess (it's created automatically)
Maybe few more. Tweaking these solve the issue.


How does this answer the issue?
